# Replace/override JRE classes (in Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

I have a project which has on its build path another project in which there is a java.lang package with a modified String implementation inside. Somehow it used to be that I started this project with a simple run configuration using stock OpenJDK 7 JRE and the modified String class was loaded (I think at least because in the code there is cast to an interface which is only implemented by the modified String). However recently I might have changed something (I don't know what) and I get a runtime ClassCastException obviously because the original String class is loaded.
I tried in a demo project replacing the String class myself and although the auto-complete and go to declaration returned my String class when I started the application this was not the case and stock String was loaded and my app wouldn't work.

The question is: how to replace (/override) classes from JRE (without using a custom classloader)? Also how my experience can be justified?

Comment: Replacing the standard JDK classes by your own custom versions is a horrible idea that might break everything. Please do not do this.

Comment: `String` is a `final` class, not meant to be extended. If you want to change the implementation to provide something else, then putting it in your own package and leaving the JDK alone would be a better idea. I agree with Jesper though, it's probably not a good idea to wholesale change standard classes.

Comment: I understand it is not a good idea but my project involves instrumentation of Java bytecode which changes classes in the end. So it is inevitable to change some if not all JRE classes. The question remains: how could I experience what I described?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to [overload JDK core classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BGBGEDBG) you can use the `-Xbootclasspath` option.

Under eclipse you can also configure the (boot) classpath of a run configuration in its respective classpath tab.